# Concatenating dataframes, renaming new index, dropping old index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

After concatenating multiple dataframes, how can I assign a name to the new index, and drop the old indexes.

I have 40 files that I'm combining into one dataframe.  Each one has an index of 1-64974.
In the final CSV, I want one index called "HandNumber" that goes from 1 to 2598960

```
#loops through files appending them into an list of dataframes called df_list 
df_combined = pd.concat(df_list)
df_combined = df_combined.sort_values(by=['Card1ID', 'Card2ID', 'Card3ID', 'Card4ID', 'Card5ID'])
df_combined.to_csv(filename_out)
```

CSV currently has no header for the new index:

```
,HandNumber,etc,etc 
1,1,A,B 
2,2,A,B 
...
64975,1,A,B 
64976,2,A,B 
etc...
```

What I want is:
HandNumber,etc,etc

```
1,A,B 
2,A,B 
...
64975,A,B 
64976,A,B 
etc...
```

Comment: You can simply reset the `index` before saving the combined dataframe to `csv` file like this:  `df_combined.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(filename_out)`

Comment: 1) drop `HandNumber` before concat, 2) concat with `ignore_index=True`, 3) `rename_axis` to `HandNumber`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma response gave me same result.

Comment: @QuangHoang - I got the correct numbers,columns now, but used  df_combined.index.name = 'HandNumber' before the to_csv instead of df_combined.rename_axis('HandNumber').  I can post answer or you can...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do with chaining:

```
(pd.concat([d.drop('HandNumber', axis=1) for d in df_list], 
            ignore_index=True)
   .rename_axis(index='HandNumber')
   .to_csv('file.csv')
)
```

Option 2:

```
(pd.concat(df_list)
   .assign(HandNumber = lambda x: np.arange(len(x))+1)
   .to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
)
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know to put index= on the rename_axis.  I posted my result too. Thanks!

Comment: `index=` is implicit, but you need to reassign `df = df.rename_axis('HandNumber')` or pass `inplace=True` without reassignment`.

Comment: Can I force new index to start at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @NealWalters see Option 2, it's easier to override the `HandNumber` columns and write csv without index.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working based on @QuangHoang's comment.  Answering because he didn't have the loop code.

He said: 1) drop HandNumber before concat, 2) concat with ignore_index=True, 3) rename_axis to HandNumber

But I was able to rename the index by doing:
df_combined.index.name = 'HandNumber' before the to_csv
instead of df_combined.rename_axis('HandNumber').

```
df_list = []
# for infile in glob.glob("*.xlsx"): # another way to get the files
for i in range(0, 40):
    filename = filebase_pattern.replace("##", str(i).zfill(2))
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=data_types_for_merge)
    del df['Hand_Number']  # ADDED THIS LINE 
    df_list.append(df)

# see pd.concat documentation for more info
df_combined = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)  # MODIFIED 
print("Number of rows=", df_combined.shape[0])

print("Sorting")
df_combined = df_combined.sort_values(by=['etc'])
print("Sorted, Writing to CSV filename=", filename_out)
df_combined.index = np.arange(1, len(df_combined) + 1) #ADDED (Import numpy as np) 
#df_combined.rename_axis("HandNumber")  # See Quang's comment in his answer.
df_combined.index.name = 'HandNumber'   # ADDED THIS LINE 
df_combined.to_csv(filename_out)
```